# Entity: call stored procedure when DBContext is from DI

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ninject

I imported my stored procedure from DB to Entity Model and could you tell me how I can use it and pass parameters?

I registered my DBContext in NinjecetWebCommon:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

and now I want to get data from MyProcedure, but I get an error:

> The type 'CMS_MyProcedure_Result' is mapped as a complex type.
>   The Set method, DbSet objects, and DbEntityEntry objects can only be
>   used with entity types, not complex types.

and this is how I want to do it:

```
public class MyRepository : BaseRepository<Product>, IMyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(DbContext _dbContext)
        : base(_dbContext)
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<ProductDisplayDTO> GetProducts(int catId, int languageId)
    {
        return = _dbContext.Set<CMS_MyProcedure_Result>();
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to call stored procedure with parameters when Ninject (Dependency injection) is using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is :-

```
public class StoredProcedure
{
    public List<CMS_MyProcedure_Result> GetCMSResult({StoredProcedureParameters})
    {
        return _dbContext.CMS_MyProcedure({StoredProcedureParameters}).ToList();
    }
}
```

and you can called it like

```
StoredProcedure storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure();
List<CMS_MyProcedure_Result> cmsResult = storedProcedure.GetCMSResult({StoredProcedureParameters});
```

Comment: But I can't see `CMS_MyProcedure` in `_dbContext` (because of Ninject dependency Injection). I must go with `_dbContext.Set<CMS_MyProcedure_Result>()`, but I dont know where I can pass parameters there.